# How to align two elements to imply something

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

`$$m=3, n=3 \implies \binom{n}{m}_{R}=\binom{3}{3}_{R}=\binom{5}{3}$$`
I am trying to create an alignment for m=3 and n=3 to be placed vertically together to imply the binomial. Maybe use`\multicol{}`?

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: You should never use the `$$ ... $$` construct, which is plain TeX syntax, and can lead  to bad spacing. Use the LaTeX syntax: `\[ ... \]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Bernard. I'm new to latex so this will be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking for, `aligned` is your friend

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}m&=3\\n&=3\end{aligned} \implies \binom{n}{m}_{R}=\binom{3}{3}_{R}=\binom{5}{3}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I get it to be on the left of the document?

Comment: If by "left of the document" you mean inline math, then use `$...$` instead of `\[...\]`.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility, with the `matrix*` environment from `mathtools` (needless to load `amsmath` in this case):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{matrix*}[r]n=3\\[0.4ex]m=3\end{matrix*} \implies \binom{n}{m}_{\!\!R}=\binom{3}{3}_{\!\!R}=\binom{5}{3}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]